# Ubuntu Installation in Asus Tuff Gaming FX505GD

Tags: partitioning, asus

I want only one OS that is Ubuntu (have the flashdrive ready with 20.01). While installation the process stopped because of RTS. Can someone help me with step by step instructions to install Ubuntu and delete Windows 10?

SPECS:

- Model: **Asus FX505GD**
- RAM: **8 GB**
- SDD: **256 GB (currently, Windows 10 is installed on it)**
- HDD: **1 TB**
- Graphics card: **GTX1050**

Thank you - Sharika

Comment: 20.01?  Do you mean Ubuntu 20.10? or the 2020-October release (Ubuntu uses a *year.month* format for releases, and there was no release in 2020-January or 20.01)

Comment: Sorry - Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wipe out Windows, it should be easy.

Boot with a LiveUSB, start `gparted` and create a new `gpt` partition table on your SSD. Then there should be no problems to install Ubuntu.

Intel RST is supported by Linux. The problems arise when Windows is install in some RAID mode and you want to keep it.

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and didn't even noticed that it was installed in RST mode.

Comment: Hi Pilot6 - I tried creating the partition in the Disk however I am unable to shrink and create new space. Would you know how to go about this? I am using Aus FX505GD

Comment: Create a new partition table. This will remove all existing partitions. You don't need to create "new space". The installer should create EFI and / partitions automatically.

Comment: Hi Pilot6 - I am technologically challenged, I m sorry...

Comment: It all started with Bluetooth being disabled in my laptop which was working perfectly. With all the issues with MS10, I decided to move to ubuntu